# Rspec nested controller create method does not increase count by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, nested, associations, nested-attributes

I am testing an Invoice model (a Client has many invoices, an Invoice belongs to a Client) and trying to check whether the create method works.

This is what I have come up with:

```
before do
  @valid_invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)
  @valid_client = @valid_invoice.client
end

it "creates a new Invoice" do
    expect {
      post :create, { invoice: @valid_client.invoices.build(valid_attributes), client_id: @valid_client.to_param }
    }.to change(Invoice, :count).by(1)
  end
```

This is my invoice factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :invoice do
        association :client
        gross_amount 3.14
        net_amount 3.14
        number "MyString"
        payment_on "2013-01-01"
        vat_rate 0.19
    end
end
```

This is the create method in the invoices_controller:

```
def create
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
@invoice = @client.invoices.build(params[:invoice])

respond_to do |format|
  if @invoice.save
    format.html { redirect_to([@invoice.client, @invoice], :notice => 'Invoice was successfully created.') }
    format.json { render :json => @invoice, :status => :created, :location => [@invoice.client, @invoice] }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @invoice.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

And these are the valid attributes, ie the attributes needed for an invoice to be created successfully:

```
def valid_attributes
{
  gross_amount: 3.14,
  net_amount: 3.14,
  number: "MyString",
  payment_on: "2013-01-01",
  vat_rate: 0.19
}
end
```

These are all valid. Maybe the client_id is missing?

It is only telling me that the count did not change by one - so I am not sure what the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the `create` method work? I'm assuming it wants its params to be a hash of attributes, not an already-initialized `Invoice` object?

Comment: Please see question edit. I added the create method. Yes, it wants an :invoice params hash.

Comment: It seems like you're most likely getting a validation error on your invoice, which would not save anything to the database, and not increase the invoice count. I would recommend doing a unit-level test using `create!` and/or `save!`, which will raise actual exceptions if for any reason the invoice can't be saved.

Comment: @JasonSwett I took these values from the factory above. In all other tests they work, and I do test for valid attributes with that factory. The only difference between valid_attributes and the factory is that in the factory there is a client_id. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gregates - Your answer was right, why did you remove it? :-) Post it again and I will check it as best answer.

This is the solution:

```
post :create, { invoice: valid_attributes, client_id: @valid_client.to_param }, valid_session
```

instead of

```
post :create, { invoice: @valid_client.invoices.build(valid_attributes), client_id: @valid_client.to_param }
```

in the test.

Also, I had to change the number in the valid_attributes. Debugging every single validation showed me that it was the same as in the factory - but must instead be unique. This solved it for me! Thanks for everyone's help!